# Horizontal scroll event not firing for react window

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized, react-window

OnScroll events are not firing for a horizontal scrollbar in list implementation of react-window.

Minimal replication is at - https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-https-dyhvu

In the given example we can see that for native implementation both horizontal and vertical scroll events are fired(check console)

In a react-window implementation of a list, only vertical(which is virtualized) scroll events are fired, not the horizontal ones.

Is there a way to fire the event for horizontal scroll event for a vertically virtualized list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After digging found solution using `outerRef` prop on `List` and attaching custom `scroll` event to it.

Solution - https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-sunset-zrddq